# Xamarin set password to SQLite database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

The conn.setPassword and conn.open have error, can SQLite.NET set the password to the sqlite database?

```
private void Btnsign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=user.db3;Version=3;");
        conn.SetPassword("password");
        conn.open();
        var data = conn.Table<login>();
        var data1 = data.Where(x => x.username == txtusername.Text && x.password == txtPassword.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        if (data1 != null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Username or Password invalid", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my knowledge it is not possible for free

Comment: While Microsoft uses this library in some parts of documentation, this is just an open source library, not Xamarin so your wording is not correct, I've updated it.

Comment: okok updated me here

Comment: check this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91691/how-to-use-sqlite-with-password-protection-on-access

Comment: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#using-sqlcipher and there is the open source version of SQLCipher for Android (community edition) via https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/

Comment: but how to add the sqlcipher to the code?

Comment: @LauTan You will have to do the work yourself: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

Comment: but the sqlcipher must buy to set database password,right?